# Dual monitor not working properly

Tags: display, hdmi, windows-11, amd-radeon, displayport

Setup is very simple, I bought a new RX 6600 with 3 DP and 1 HDMI.

First port is connected to a DP->HDMI adapter and then to the main monitor.

Second port is HDMI cable directly connected to an old SONY BRAVIA TV.

Problem is: only the main monitor (through DP->HDMI adapter) is visible at BIOS time, then, as windows is booting up, only the second monitor (HDMI direct) is visible. After loading windows, only this second monitor keeps visible until I unplug the main monitor from the back of PC and plug it back in. When I do that, both displays go blank for a moment and come up to life right after.

Tried different DP->HDMI adapters and HDMI cables. Even tried a DP->DVI adapter instead, but got the same results.

The adapter, cables, GPU, monitors, ..., shouldn't be the problem cos everything works fine if I replug DP connector from the PC.

Running Windows 11 with the latest updates and latest drivers from AMD for the GPU.

What am I possibly doing wrong?