# One of two monitors stays black (off) after I login back from locked screen on Windows 11

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-11, lenovo-laptop, usb-c

Reproduction of the issue:
Windows 11 locks session and turns off monitors according to the corresponding power settings.
When i attempt to log back in, one of my two monitors stays turned off / black.
It never happens when I turn on / reboot PC and then I log in.

Occurrence: random

*This didn't help me:*
[Dual monitor not working properly](https://superuser.com/q/1756671/1740976) -> difference is that my issue never happens after booting up from turned off state.

Somewhat helps:
re-pluging USB-C to HDMI adapter cable -> it moves active monitor from secondary to the laptop monitor.

Switching multiple screen settings in windows - >  sometimes doesn't do anything, other times turns on both monitors after switching from extended to this-pc and back to extended screen.

I tried fiddling with Windows 11 screen settings. - > nothing seems to change.

Relevant system specs:

```
Computer:      Yoga Duet 7-13IML05 - Type 82AS 
Monitor:       AOC 2461W        

BIOS:          ERCN29WW, 05/17/2022
Graphics:      Intel UHD Graphics (Comet Lake-U GT2) [V0] [Lenovo]
               Intel UHD Graphics, 1024 MB 

OS:            Microsoft Windows 11 Professional (x64) Build 22621.1413
```

Any idea what could fix it permanently?

Comment: Question subject does not match description. Does OP mean 1 of the monitors does NOT turn on after session recovers?

Comment: I am creating an edit request to change "not stays" -> "stays" because OP says "one of my two monitors stays turned off / black" explicitly in question description.

Comment: Thanks , it was oversight on my side. ( Monitor won't turn on and stays black.)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I had the same issue here. Difference is that I use a Intel NUC and have two external monitors (no build-ins like laptops). The one that had the problem is the one directly plugged into the HDMI port of the NUC. The other connected with USB-C -> HDMI is fine. If I switch cable, the faulty monitor also changed (i.e., always faulty on the one directly plugged into HDMI port).